# Why is this function not running on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple question, I've written a simple calculate function and it works perfectly, although I am having an issue, because it only work with the .change() method and doesn't when the document is loaded. This function I have written is dependent on the Numerals library that is included in the page footer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function compute() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  var price = parseFloat($('.price', row).val().replace(',', '.'));

  var quantity = parseFloat($('.quantity', row).val(), 10);
  var total = price * quantity;
  totalCleaned = numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00');
  $('.total', row).html(totalCleaned);

  var grandTotal = 0;
  var totalsum = 0;
  $('.total').each(function() {
      totalsum += numeral().unformat($(this).text());
      grandTotal = numeral(totalsum.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00'); 
      $('.net-total').html(grandTotal);
  });

  console.log(grandTotal);

}

compute(); // this is where I am trying to start the function on load
$('.price, .quantity').change(compute);


});
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` supposed to be? When you first call `compute()` `$(this)` will be equal to the entire DOM - no idea what it'd thing the closest `tr` element is, but it's probably not the one you're attempting to target.

Comment: well put alert(row); after  var row = $(this).closest('tr'); and see what you get

Comment: "Included in the page footer." Shouldn't you load the library before you have the `document.ready()`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger an initial state change with `change()`. This retains the correct `this` scope for the call:

e.g.

```
$('.price, .quantity').change(compute).change();
```

But the code needs to be inside the same scope as the function it calls or it can't see the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function compute() {
         // Snip...
    });
    $('.price, .quantity').change(compute).change();
});
```

Technically you may not want to trigger on all matches, in which case trigger change on the `first` only:

```
    $('.price, .quantity').change(compute).first().change();
```

Answer (score 6):

> because it only work with the .change() method and doesn't when the document is loaded

Your function refers to `this`:

```
...
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
...
```

When called from a `.change` handler, the meaning of `this` this essentially "the element which has changed" - so your method works just fine.

When called without this context, `this` has no relevant meaning - it almost certainly refers to the `window`.

Comment: Hmm, any work arounds, I have a table with multiple rows and every row has an input with amount and an input with price. Thank you Jamiec for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` corresponds to the current object / element. When your function is inside `.ready()` , `$(this)` has no relevance and refers to the document.

When the same is called from a `.change()` event, `$(this)` now corresponds to the element that has changed and thus it works.

To make it work in `.ready()` , you need to first find the closest tr in respect to a particular element not `$(this)`. For this you can use an `Id` and declare the function like wise.

Answer (score 0):

You keep your function definition out side of the document.ready() as below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  compute(); // this is where I am trying to start the function on load
 $('.price, .quantity').change(compute);
 });
function compute() {
 var row = $('.price, .quantity').closest('tr');

 var price = parseFloat($('.price', row).val().replace(',', '.'));

var quantity = parseFloat($('.quantity', row).val(), 10);
var total = price * quantity;
totalCleaned = numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00');
$('.total', row).html(totalCleaned);

var grandTotal = 0;
var totalsum = 0;
$('.total').each(function() {
  totalsum += numeral().unformat($(this).text());
  grandTotal = numeral(totalsum.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00'); 
  $('.net-total').html(grandTotal);
});

console.log(grandTotal);

}
```